# Why am I accidentally creating palindromes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby to take in a string and reverse the order of the letters (so that the last letter becomes the first, etc.)

When I use the below code, I accidentally create a palindrome by taking half of the string and repeating it:

```
 def reverse(word)

  i = 0
  new_word = word
  
  while i < word.length
    
   new_word [i] = word [word.length - i - 1]
    
    i += 1 
  
  end
  
 return new_word
  
end

puts reverse("cat")          # => "tac"
puts reverse("programming")  # => "gnimmargorp"
puts reverse("bootcamp")     # => "pmactoob"
```

However, when I use the below code, I get it right:

```
 def reverse(word)

  i = 0
  new_word = ""
  
  while i < word.length
    
   new_word [i] = word [word.length - i - 1]
    
    i += 1 
  
  end
  
 return new_word
  
end

puts reverse("cat")          # => "tac"
puts reverse("programming")  # => "gnimmargorp"
puts reverse("bootcamp")     # => "pmactoob"
```

I just changed word to "" (line 4) and it works. Why?

My suspicion is that the string (word) itself is changing with each iteration, but it isn't supposed to do that is it?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My suspicion is that the string (word) itself is changing with each iteration, but it isn't supposed to do that is it?

Your suspicion is spot-on.

```
new_word = word
```

This does not create a new string. It tells `new_word` to refer to the *same* list as `word`. Ruby is one of a handful of languages where strings are actually mutable objects. So when you modify `new_word` with `[]=`, you're *also* modifying `word`. As you've already noticed, you can start with an empty string

```
new_word = ""
```

Alternatively, if you want to start with `word` and modify it (there are certainly some algorithms where doing so can be beneficial), we can use the `#dup` method, which performs a shallow copy of the data

```
new_word = word.dup
```

You can check whether two variables refer to the exact same object (as opposed to simply looking the same) using `#equal?`

```
puts(new_word.equal? word)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Why would I want to change the original string using a new string? In other words, why is this functionality there?

Comment: The idea is similar to why would I want to change my original car with a new engine?  Perhaps the user is expecting their reference string to change with the help of your method.  It might be silly for me to expect a brand new car for only wanting the update.

Comment: Suppose I want to replace all vowels with question marks in a string. If the string is several kilobytes, it makes a lot more sense to modify it in place than to copy the whole thing when I'm only changing a small fraction of it.